# splitting of date column to day, month, year in python 2.7

Tags: python

I  am currently working on a dataset of 8 000 rows.

I want to split my date column by day, month, year. dtype for the date is                   object

How to convert the whole column of date by date. month, year?

A sample of the date of my dataset is shown below:

```
date
01-01-2016
01-01-2016
01-01-2016
01-01-2016
01-01-2016
```

df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['date'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], infer_datetime_format=True)
print(df)
dt=datetime.strptime('date',"%d-%m-%y")
print(dt)
This is the code I am using for date splitting but it is showing mean error
ValueError: time data 'date' does not match format '%d-%m-%y'

Comment: Show the code that makes that error, please.

Comment: `Please suggest me a code for this.` We can help if you have a question about your code, but this isn't a "free code" site.

Comment: df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['date'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], infer_datetime_format=True)
print(df)
dt=datetime.strptime('date',"%d-%m-%y")
print(dt)                                                                                           ValueError: time data 'date' does not match format '%d-%m-%y'                  This is the code I am working on

Answer (score 4):

If you have pandas you can do this:

```
import pandas as pd

# Recreate your dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(date=['01-01-2016']*6))
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

# Create 3 new columns
df[['year','month','day']] = df.date.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.strftime("%Y,%m,%d").split(",")))

df
```

Returns

```
        date  year month day
0 2016-01-01  2016    01  01
1 2016-01-01  2016    01  01
2 2016-01-01  2016    01  01
3 2016-01-01  2016    01  01
4 2016-01-01  2016    01  01
5 2016-01-01  2016    01  01
```

Or without the formatting options:

```
df['year'],df['month'],df['day'] = df.date.dt.year, df.date.dt.month, df.date.dt.day

df
```

Returns

```
        date  year  month  day
0 2016-01-01  2016      1    1
1 2016-01-01  2016      1    1
2 2016-01-01  2016      1    1
3 2016-01-01  2016      1    1
4 2016-01-01  2016      1    1
5 2016-01-01  2016      1    1
```

Comment: Your first code if I am running for 8781 rows. It splitting the same date while my dataset has different dates. I am changing *6 To *8781

Comment: @user143072 My code is a sample code. You should use your own dataframe.